# Device Physical button click handling

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to get a callback on click of home and recent apps buttons of the device?

Although we can handle back, I want to handle the others too I searched but couldn't find any way for this one.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: of course not, but you can using another way that is lifecycle method

Answer (score 0):

We have no callback for this event, but you can use the lifecycle methods to detect when user click button home

Below is an example from [App state](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/active/) &&
      nextAppState === 'background'
    ) {
      console.log('user click button home');
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```